# Create the xAxys with a array of strings instead of an array of integers - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I need to use an array of strings instead of an array of integers to create my **xAxys** on Highcharts.

Anyone already tried to do this or can help me make this happen?

My mock data to be used on this chart will be something like:

```
    var weekNoArray = [32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34],
        retailerNamesArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        clicksArray = [43, 48, 62, 63, 43, 39, 27, 30, 43, 49, 34, 24, 47, 45, 59, 64, 48, 47],
        series = [];
```

The `retailerNamesArray` variable needs to be used to create my **xAxys**.

What I already have tried to generate the series:

```
series = generateData(weekNoArray, retailerNamesArray, clicksArray);

function generateData(weekNoArray, retailerNamesArray, clicksArray) {
    var ret = {},
        ps = [],
        series = [],
        len = weekNoArray.length;

    //concat to get points
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ps[i] = {
            x: weekNoArray[i],
            y: clicksArray[i],
            n: retailerNamesArray[i]
        };
    }
    retailerNamesArray = [];
    //generate series and split points
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var p = ps[i],
            sIndex = $.inArray(p.n, retailerNamesArray);

        if (sIndex < 0) {
            sIndex = retailerNamesArray.push(p.n) - 1;
            series.push({
                name: p.n,
                data: []
            });
        }
        series[sIndex].data.push(p);
    }
    return series;
}



$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Retaielr Clicks',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Date',
        x: -20
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Clicks'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: series
});
```

Running example: [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/RUZb2/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of this code `weekNoArray` where used to set x axis values and xAxis of `linear` type. Now if you want to use `category` type axis you should at least:

- change `weekNoArray` values to start from 0
- set categories for x axis

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/

Comment: But I want set value of x using the strings values.
In the way you did, the validation of x axis continues using the integer value, do you know how can I make using a string value?

Thank you!

Comment: @ValdeciGomes There is no such way to set x as string - axis must have numbers. If you are using categorized axis then numbers for labels are added automatically, but there are still numbers used. Other way would be to set data without x values - they will get their x values assigned automatically. X values still will be numbers. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/1/

Comment: Thank you Kacper! But the values of the retailerNameArray always
appears in the first column of teste1 in your example, Do you know How can I make the correct position of this variable?

Look this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/2/, the value "GRUPO 4" is the last value of the retailerNameArray, it was to appear in the last column, but it appears in the first column, Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: One way that you will not like is to set x. Other way is to add 5 null points, so 6th (your GRUPO 4) will be placed at last column. You should define rules of how points will be placed or add more data. Example that works for this data: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/3/

Comment: I'll need to set X. My data is defined in a dynamic way, so the second option won't work.  Do you know, how can I set the value with strings and these strings define the integer value of x, similar the first example?
Thanks!

Comment: For example, set that the GRUPO 4 belongs to second column?

Comment: One way would be to set y data for that point as array [x,y] and parse it properly. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/4/ You should define how is information about x coordinate passed - later it's just a matter of parsing the data. It would be more efficient if you could limit parsing operations, but it is up to you. Where in raw data will the information about what x value be stored?

Comment: I resolve this problem creating a function to transform my strings values in integer values and with this  values I create the xAxis, like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/8/

Thanks for your help Kacper!

Answer (score 0):

As @Kacper Madej said, there is no such way to set x as a string - axis must have numbers.

So, I solved this problem by creating a function that transforms my strings values of the array `retailerNamesArray` in integer values, and then with these values, I could create my **xAxis**!.

Running example: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rt4pthvn/8)